# Calculate if a number has changed "radically"

Tags: standard-deviation, means

Trying to apply math to a computer program problem:
I want to find out if the size of a text file has changed "radically" compared to the last X successfully processed files.
So far I have calculated the standard deviation from the last 20 files size in bytes, but not sure how to proceed and apply that number on the file size (yeah my 9th grade math is somewhat cloudy!).

How should I calculate this?

Comment: Well, you have to decide what "radically" means.  For a rule of thumb, there's the [$68-95-99.7$ rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) which tells you what percent of random samples should lie within $1,2,3\sigma$ of the mean, assuming normality.  That's good enough for most informal questions.

Comment: I think it is a good approach. Check if the current file size differs from the averaged file size (over the last $n$ measurement cycles) by more than a specific amount or ratio. The details depend on the differences that you expect and the exact situation.

Comment: Some context: The file contains rows (CSV file) so i'm interested in, but loading all files and calculating number of rows inside each file is way too slow (files contains around 250.000 lines each) so though the file size itself would be an ok measure. A "radical" change (the number can vary but lets for the sake of example say +-25% change in file size compared to the last X successful imports) in file size would indicate that an incomplete or faulty import was created